# how to compile java with multiple files using command line

Tags: java, linux, class

I am pretty new to Java and Linux. I can't use an IDE but i have jdk installed (obviously). I have three .java files that i want to compile. One is the main code file and two small classes. how do i compile them using terminal?
these files are called:

> - main.java
> - object.java (Object.class when compiled)
> - living.java (Living.class when compiled)

object.java and living.java only have a constructor for now that i want to call

i've tried

```
javac main.java #this seems to be the right one
javac main.java object.java living.java
javac main.java Object.class Living.class
```

in terminal and

```
import object.java;
import living.java;

import Object.class;
import Living.class;

import object;
import living;

import Object;
import Living;
```

in the main.java file

but nothing seems to work

when i use

```
import Living;
```

in the code it tells me that it misses a ; or .

, when using precompiled

```
import Living.class
```

in the code i get

```
error: class, interface, or enum expected
import <Object.class>;
```

in the terminal and when i try

```
import living.java
```

in the code i get

```
error: package living does not exist
import living.java;
```

in terminal

so what am i doing wrong? do i have to import precompiled classes or java codefiles? do i have to tell javac all files i want to use or only the main.java file? main.java compiles without error when i don't try to import one of the classes. And if i have to use .jar files please explain and give an example

Comment: Note that if all three classes are in the same package, you don't need to `import` them in your code.

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-javac-command/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Arnaud commented: "Note that if all three classes are in the same package, you don't need to import them in your code"

i don't need to import these classes in this case and leaving import away works.

Answer (score 1):

Your file name has to match the class name, e.g. if you have a `class Living {...` your file name has to be named `Living.java`. Be aware of the same character casing here. If you use `package xyz;` in `Living.java`, you also have to place your file in the subdirectory `xyz` (e.g. `xyz/Living.java`).

Importing is to be done by `import Living;`, with the same case. On using `package xyz;` in your `Living.java`, you have to use `import xyz.Living;`.
Classes within the same package doesn't need to be imported.

You compile your files by using `javac Living.java` or with package `javac xyz/Living.java`. The `javac` will produce the `Living.class`/`xyz/Living.class` file.

Same with `Main.java`.

To run a classes main method, you have to run the `java` executable with the class name, which contains the `static void main(...)` method, e.g. `java Main` (or `java xyz.Main` if Main has a `package xyz;`).

Never create an `Object.java`, since `Object` is already reserved...

BTW: maybe you follow one of the many tutorials available online, to get a first glance on java...

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer but @Arnaud already commented the answer. i don't have to use import and that works. Then all tutorials online tell me to use an IDE. And yes, for bigger projects i will keep in mind to avoid Object as a class and give file.java and file.class the same name